# Paste image from clipboard to html page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, clipboard

I'm learning angular and I'm trying to use copy image from clipboard and paste  it in html web page.
 I found a solution in Javascript that i want to convert to typeScript. But it doesn't work when I test it. It works fine on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KJW4E/1739/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <script>
    var CLIPBOARD = new CLIPBOARD_CLASS("my_canvas", true);

    /**
     * image pasting into canvas
     * 
     * @param {string} canvas_id - canvas id
     * @param {boolean} autoresize - if canvas will be resized
     */
    function CLIPBOARD_CLASS(canvas_id, autoresize) {
        var _self = this;
        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_id);
        var ctx = document.getElementById(canvas_id).getContext("2d");
        var ctrl_pressed = false;
        var command_pressed = false;
        var paste_event_support;
        var pasteCatcher;

        //handlers
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            _self.on_keyboard_action(e);
        }, false); //firefox fix
        document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            _self.on_keyboardup_action(e);
        }, false); //firefox fix
        document.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
            _self.paste_auto(e);
        }, false); //official paste handler

        //constructor - we ignore security checks here
        this.init = function () {
            pasteCatcher = document.createElement("div");
            pasteCatcher.setAttribute("id", "paste_ff");
            pasteCatcher.setAttribute("contenteditable", "");
            pasteCatcher.style.cssText = 'opacity:0;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:10px;margin-left:-20px;';
            document.body.appendChild(pasteCatcher);

            // create an observer instance
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                    if (paste_event_support === true || ctrl_pressed == false || mutation.type != 'childList'){
                        //we already got data in paste_auto()
                        return true;
                    }

                    //if paste handle failed - capture pasted object manually
                    if(mutation.addedNodes.length == 1) {
                        if (mutation.addedNodes[0].src != undefined) {
                            //image
                            _self.paste_createImage(mutation.addedNodes[0].src);
                        }
                        //register cleanup after some time.
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            pasteCatcher.innerHTML = '';
                        }, 20);
                    }
                });
            });
            var target = document.getElementById('paste_ff');
            var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
            observer.observe(target, config);
        }();
        //default paste action
        this.paste_auto = function (e) {
            paste_event_support = false;
            if(pasteCatcher != undefined){
                pasteCatcher.innerHTML = '';
            }
            if (e.clipboardData) {
                var items = e.clipboardData.items;
                if (items) {
                    paste_event_support = true;
                    //access data directly
                    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") !== -1) {
                            //image
                            var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
                            var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                            var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(blob);
                            this.paste_createImage(source);
                        }
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    //wait for DOMSubtreeModified event
                    //https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=891247
                }
            }
        };
        //on keyboard press
        this.on_keyboard_action = function (event) {
            k = event.keyCode;
            //ctrl
            if (k == 17 || event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) {
                if (ctrl_pressed == false)
                    ctrl_pressed = true;
            }
            //v
            if (k == 86) {
                if (document.activeElement != undefined && document.activeElement.type == 'text') {
                    //let user paste into some input
                    return false;
                }

                if (ctrl_pressed == true && pasteCatcher != undefined){
                    pasteCatcher.focus();
                }
            }
        };
        //on kaybord release
        this.on_keyboardup_action = function (event) {
            //ctrl
            if (event.ctrlKey == false && ctrl_pressed == true) {
                ctrl_pressed = false;
            }
            //command
            else if(event.metaKey == false && command_pressed == true){
                command_pressed = false;
                ctrl_pressed = false;
            }
        };
        //draw pasted image to canvas
        this.paste_createImage = function (source) {
            var pastedImage = new Image();
            pastedImage.onload = function () {
                if(autoresize == true){
                    //resize
                    canvas.width = pastedImage.width;
                    canvas.height = pastedImage.height;
                }
                else{
                    //clear canvas
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                }
                ctx.drawImage(pastedImage, 0, 0);
            };
            pastedImage.src = source;
        };
    }




    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    1. Copy image data into clipboard or press Print Screen <br>
    2. Press Ctrl+V (page/iframe must be focused):
    <br /><br />
    <button onclick="alert('Hello! I am an alert box!!');"></button>
    <canvas style="border:1px solid grey;" id="my_canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I am using google chrome Version 70.0.3538.77

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"but it doesnt work when i test it"* - what exactly doesn't work? Can you please provide some console error messages for us.

Comment: @MouadSbiti Can you create a Stackblitz demo showing the typescript attempt please?

Comment: It works fine for me. https://angular-6ckpxd.stackblitz.io

Comment: @user184994 Hey , sorry i am not familiar with stackblitz , besides, i didnt try it in typescript

Comment: @Zze Did you copy and paste the code i posted and worked? weird ... for me it doesnt work

Comment: The only change I made was putting the snippet inside the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook. The rest is copy pasted verbatim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above, it sounds like you were trying to execute your bindings in the `constructor` of your component instead of within [`ngOnInit`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). This is a classic gotcha as the constructor spins up well before (in most cases) before the content on screen is finished rendering. `ngOnInit` is called as the component finalises its instantiation process.

https://angular-6ckpxd.stackblitz.io

The errors you receive are because typescript is strongly typed where javascript is not. You are pasting javascript code in (which is fine in most cases) but will need some casting to `any` if you want to eradicate most of them.

Comment: Hey , thank you so much, it worked. But i still get this error "Property 'webkitURL' does not exist on type 'Window'. "  Here :  var URLObj : any = window.URL || window.webkitURL .

Comment: @MsIsem try: `var URLObj = window.URL || (window as any).webkitURL;`